# Voice Output in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, speech-synthesis

Is it possible to access the speech synthesis feature of the iOS that is used for accessibility?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text to speech on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone)

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example using `AVSpeechSynthesizer` on iOS 7:

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *synthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Hey Guys"];
[synthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

To change the voice use:

```
utterance.voice = [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice voiceWithLanguage:@"de-DE"];
```

To get a list of all voices:

```
NSLog(@"voices %@", [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices]);
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you can find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone) SO question helpful. [FLITE](http://artofsystems.blogspot.com/2009/02/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-with-flite.html) also brings speech synthesis to iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Now, since ios7 you can use the built in `AVSpeechSynthesizer`