# How to make my iOS quiz app with vocal lecture

Tags: ios, ios7

I have a quiz and I want that my app read the question and the responses to the user.
Is there any iOS lib to use?

Comment: Better read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552250/voice-output-in-ios/20748015#20748015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `AVSpeechSynthesizer` class (https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

```
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [[AVSpeechUtterance alloc] initWithString:@"Your text"];
AVSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc] init];
[speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: it helps, that's what I want