# Generate voice programmatically - Sound processing

Tags: iphone, android, objective-c

Could we write a program that can generate voice? The code would allow us to manipulate the voice too. What are the requirements? I am basically interested in generating voice through iPhone and Android.

Comment: I'm not sure if it could be done "rogrammitcally"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text to speech on iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone)

Comment: Not a text to voice converter.... I am asking for generating voice.

Comment: What kind of "voice" you want to "generate" ?? are you trying to generate any "sound" in general? by creating a file and filling it with bytes?

Comment: @Sheikh Probably a sound which can be controlled, the loudness, pitch etc.

Comment: Trying to create an equaliser kinda thing? i don't know whether there's any SoundProcessing library available for Android.. :-/

Comment: @socialCircus Thanks. It was really hard to spot!

Answer (score 2):

Android has a [text-to-speech API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html). It may not be supported on all devices, but there are separate apps which implement it.

Comment: Thank you ,however I want to create voice @Pontus. Like when you run the code it will generate voice.

Comment: Why do you want to do it yourself? What's missing in the TTS functionality? Speech synthesis requires quite a lot of linguistic competence and data.

Comment: If you just want to alter pitch and speed, check the API... it's already there for you!