# How can I add NSSpeechSynthesizer Class Reference?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

How can i add NSSpeechSynthesizer Class Reference.
I think it is in
**/System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework**.
However there is no such framework name in framework window when I am clicking add existing frame work.

Can any one help me to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppKit framework is MacOS framework, not iOS, and so NSSpeechSynthesizer class is also available on Mac only.

Check this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone) for the list of some 3rd-party text-to-speach engines available on iPhone

Answer (score 5):

VSSpeechSynthesizer is available for the iOS - but it is a private API and as such will likely be rejected from the app store.  However you can still make apps for private consumption.  I consider this a bug as it makes creating accessible apps for the partially sighted for instance, harder.  I have filed **Bug ID #: 9451650 Bug Title: VSSpeechSynthesizer is Private**

I currently use Flite TTS in my App.  All hopes fix on the Nuance integration in iOS5 being available as a public API.

Answer (score 0):

You can find it inside iPhone SDK
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices