# Best sdk or api which convert text into speech

Tags: iphone, text-to-speech

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text to speech on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone)

I have a string say "Hello world".
Please suggest me the best Api or sdk that can convert this text string into speech?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPhone sdk don't have any functionality to convert text into speech.

You can use third party sdk, see the below links,

http://artofsystems.blogspot.com/2009/02/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-with-flite.html

http://github.com/KingOfBrian/VocalKit

Comment: i had tried FLite sdk for tts conversion but still i am unable to produce an childs sound using this sdk can you help me out??

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you using http://www.politepix.com/openears/