# ios capture audio file from user's speech

Tags: ios, audio, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm doing an app which converts from speech to text. I have googled and find that google speech api is a google choice. Now I meet a question: When user speak to ios device, how can I capture the audio file? does any Frameworks or APIs should be introduced? And what's the type of raw audio file, WAV or MP3? Thank you.

Comment: To let you know mp3 isn't a raw audio format; it's compressed.

Comment: @Letrstotheprez OK it's my mistake, but that's not the point, I really want to know just a tip about reading audio from microphone

Comment: Yea I got that sorry, I just wanted to inform you in case you didn't know.

Comment: @Letrstotheprez I have solve the problem after I read Apple's demo named SpeakHere, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a look at some of the existing StackOverflow questions on this subject. Try [Speech to text Conversion.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776402/speech-to-text-conversion) or [What is the current best speech recognition API for ios to match few keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9202583/what-is-the-current-best-speech-recognition-api-for-ios-to-match-few-keywords)