# How to convert String to Audio (Sound) file in ios (Cocos2d)?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way to convert string (character) to Audio file in iOS? My question is I have a string and that string I want to convert into sound file, Is it possible **without** using any **third party api**?

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: possible duplicate of:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/416064/text-to-speech-on-iphone

Comment: @Ajay.sorry for my incomplete question.my means without third party Api.

Comment: @Ajay,i tried this ESpeakEngine & fliteEngine 1.4 third party Api.Is't  Acceptable By Apple? and one more think it's using can i set like Sound Like Small girls or Boy (likes Kids Sound) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVSpeechSynthesizer Tutorial – [Letting Your App Speak Like Siri](http://www.devfright.com/quick-look-avspeechsynthesizer-class/)

[avspeechsynthesizer-ios-text-speech-ios-7](http://jonathanfield.me/avspeechsynthesizer-ios-text-speech-ios-7/)

but this is only available iOS 7

[image]

[sample app](http://cdn5.devfright.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/AVSpeechSynthesizer.zip)

Comment: is it possible to use with cocos2d Game engine?In cocos2d 3.0 i play all file with OALSimpleAudio player.

Comment: ,i tried this ESpeakEngine & fliteEngine 1.4 third party Api.Is't  Acceptable By Apple? and one more think it's using can i set like Sound Like Small girls or Boy (likes Kids Sound).

Comment: sorry dude i don't know

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with **iOS 7**, The [AVSpeechSynthesizer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVSpeechSynthesizer_Ref/Reference/Reference.html) class produces synthesized speech from text on an iOS device, and provides methods for controlling or monitoring the progress of ongoing speech.

EDIT: Simply add `AVFoundation` framework in your project,
Add the import statement `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`
and execute this piece of code:

```
AVSpeechSynthesizer *speechSynthesizer = [[AVSpeechSynthesizer alloc]init];
AVSpeechUtterance *utterance = [AVSpeechUtterance speechUtteranceWithString:@"Really, its very easy."];
[utterance setRate:0.5f];
[speechSynthesizer speakUtterance:utterance];
```

Comment: is it possible to use with cocos2d Game engine?In cocos2d 3.0 i play all file with OALSimpleAudio player.

Comment: I really don't know about cocos2d and game development but I think you can use any of the iOS SDK methods while using cocos2D. Cocos2D builds on the official Apple SDK – it doesn’t preclude you using any of the Apple stuff.

Comment: ,i tried this ESpeakEngine & fliteEngine 1.4 third party Api.Is't  Acceptable By Apple? and one more think it's using can i set like Sound Like Small girls or Boy (likes Kids Sound).

Comment: Using AVSpeechSynthesizer you can set male/female voice. It provides these much options [AVSpeechSynthesisVoice speechVoices]. and For kids sound you can try different voice,volume and pitch but I'm not sure. and I don't think Apple will denied using third party apis as long as they are as per their guidelines.

Comment: how to convert audio file to text file objective ?

Comment: @RamaniHitesh Checkout Google Cloud APIs, https://cloud.google.com/speech/ They have a powerful set of APIs for audio to text conversion

Comment: my project concept any mp3, audio file .wav file to convert  text format objective c but  in this concept like Speech Recognizer something so please any other ideas how is there  in this topic so please let me know

Answer (score 0):

In the previous version of IOS 7 use flute library http://artofsystems.blogspot.in/2009/02/speech-synthesis-on-iphone-with-flite.html

For IOS 7 there is inbuilt feature for Text to speech conversion avspeechsynthesizer-ios-text-speech-ios-7