# How can I play sound system with text?

Tags: ios, swift

Do we have any ways to get sound from text?

For example, we have:

```
let str = "Hello English" .
```

I want to get sound system from that text.

Comment: look into AVSpeechSynthesizer, there is a tutorial at AppCoda http://www.appcoda.com/text-to-speech-ios-tutorial/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21623251/how-to-convert-string-to-audio-sound-file-in-ios-cocos2d
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860091/ios-text-to-speech-conversion

Comment: Google : "Text To speech"

Comment: import AVFoundation         func playSound(str: String){
        let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: str)
        speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ravy Chheng answered, this uses the built-in AVFoundation library to initialize basic text-to speak function. For more information, check out the documentation by Apple: https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer

```
import AVFoundation

func playSound(str: String) {
    let speechSynthesizer = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    let speechUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: str)
    speechSynthesizer.speak(speechUtterance)
}
```